# Dynamic function call in Go

Tags: go, first-class-functions

I'm trying to dynamically call functions returning different types of `struct`.

For example, let's take the following code.

```
struct A {
   Name string
   Value  int
}

struct B {
   Name1 string
   Name2 string
   Value   float
}

func doA() (A) {
   // some code returning A
}

func doB() (B) {
   // some code returning B
}
```

I would like to pass either the function `doA` or `doB` as an argument to a generic function that would execute the function and JSON-encode the result. Like the following:

```
func Generic(w io.Writer, fn func() (interface {}) {
    result := fn()
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```

But when I do:

```
Generic(w, doA)
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot use doA (type func() (A)) as type func() (interface {})
```

Is there a way to achieve this dynamic call?

Comment: In future please be more careful when cut-n-pasting code. Your code snippet isn't even valid Go (`struct B {` vs `type B struct {` and missing `)` in the `Generic` definition). You should also `gofmt` all Go code in questions (e.g. that would remove the extraneous parentheses you have around the return types that just make it harder to read). Finally, providing a play.golang.org link can be very helpful to both those trying to answer and those readers that want to try/experiment with the issue; e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/ON15IwPwDy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, let me remark that `func() (interface{})` means the same thing as `func() interface{}`, so I'll use the shorter form.

### Passing a function of type `func() interface{}`

You can write a generic function that takes a `func() interface{}` argument as long as the function that you pass to it has type `func() interface{}`, like this:

```
type A struct {
    Name  string
    Value int
}

type B struct {
    Name1 string
    Name2 string
    Value float64
}

func doA() interface{} {
    return &A{"Cats", 10}
}

func doB() interface{} {
    return &B{"Cats", "Dogs", 10.0}
}

func Generic(w io.Writer, fn func() interface{}) {
    result := fn()
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```

You can try out this code in a live playground:

http://play.golang.org/p/JJeww9zNhE

## Passing a function as an argument of type `interface{}`

If you want to write functions `doA` and `doB` that return concretely typed values, you can pass the chosen function as an argument of type `interface{}`. Then you can use the [`reflect` package](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) to make a `func() interface{}` at run-time:

```
func Generic(w io.Writer, f interface{}) {
    fnValue := reflect.ValueOf(f)        // Make a concrete value.
    arguments := []reflect.Value{}       // Make an empty argument list.
    fnResults := fnValue.Call(arguments) // Assume we have a function. Call it.
    result := fnResults[0].Interface()   // Get the first result as interface{}.
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)    // JSON-encode the result.
}
```

More concisely:

```
func Generic(w io.Writer, fn interface{}) {
    result := reflect.ValueOf(fn).Call([]reflect.Value{})[0].Interface()
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```

Complete program:

package main

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    Name  string
    Value int
}

type B struct {
    Name1 string
    Name2 string
    Value float64
}

func doA() *A {
    return &A{"Cats", 10}
}

func doB() *B {
    return &B{"Cats", "Dogs", 10.0}
}

func Generic(w io.Writer, fn interface{}) {
    result := reflect.ValueOf(fn).Call([]reflect.Value{})[0].Interface()
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}

func main() {
    Generic(os.Stdout, doA)
    Generic(os.Stdout, doB)
}
```

Live playground:

http://play.golang.org/p/9M5Gr2HDRN

Comment: I came to that conclusion as well, but I wanted to keep the strong typing for the return values of doA() and doB(). I guess there is no way to achieve that ?

Comment: You can achieve that if you make your `Generic` function accept an argument of type `interface{}`. Please see my extended answer.

Comment: Although very interesting/informative, of course the "real" answer is "don't do this". Reflection should only be used when all else fails, it should be the *last resort* you turn to and not the first thing you try. Also note this follows the OP example of having absolutely zero error checking which is a giant no-no, never ignore errors, e.g. from `json.Encode`.

Comment: How to do that ?


 fn := "doA"
 Generic(os.Stdout, fn)

Answer (score 0):

Your return signature is different for these functions:
`fn func() (interface {})` vs. `func doA() (A)` and `func doB() (B)`

You are getting a compiler error because you are passing a function with a different signature into your `Generic` function.  To address this issue you can change your functions to return `interface{}`.

This is an example of how to do that, I am using anonymous structs and printing the return value out rather than serializing them but this applies just the same to your example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func doA() interface{} {
    return struct {
        Name  string
        Value int
    }{
        "something",
        5,
    }
}

func doB() interface{} {
    return struct {
        Name1 string
        Name2 string
        Value float64
    }{
        "something",
        "or other",
        5.3,
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", doA(), doB())
}
```

Experiment with this in the Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/orrJw2XMW8